# Pycharm: Couldn't upload helpers for remote interpreter: Authentication failed: Exhausted available authentication methods

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-server

I have used Pycharm to connect my remote server and it worked well. But after I added a second connection to another server. It reports errors: `Couldn't upload helpers for remote interpreter: Authentication failed: Exhausted available authentication methods`, and the previous connection failed as well.

Here are some measures that I took but not valid.

- Delete the new connection.
- Delete all connection and remote interpreter, then reconnect to the remote server
- Restart my laptop.

***The last thing I did and worked for me is***

go to `Deployment -> connection -> Authentication`, choose `Key pair openssh or PuTTY`, select the `private key path`. `Test Connection` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

go to `Deployment -> connection -> Authentication`, choose `Key pair openssh or PuTTY`, select the `private key path`. `Test Connection` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you face problem in Pycharm, there are high chances you are not able to SSH using Putty / Terminal (Mac). Please try ssh'ing into host via Putty / Terminal first. If you fix the issue with your Putty / Terminal (Mac), you'll automatically fix Pycharm's **Authentication Failed** Error too. That's how, I fixed mine.